# Vertical Sliding Menu Bar

Tags: css, slide

Ok so I'm trying to create a vertical sliding and I got one to almost work the way I want. It's a really simple code. There's 3 problems though:

- I need the sub menus to be closed when the page first loads
- If you quickly hover over the links the sub menus will start sliding like crazy. I need it to be more fluid and keep opening and closing. Its too sensitive
- If you hover anywhere on the screen ALIGNED to the links that slide down it'll slide. I need it to slide only when you mouse over the link it self

Here's the code: THANKS!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nav.main_menu li").hover(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown(500);   
},function(){
 $(this).children("ul").slideUp(300);      
});
});
</script>


<nav class="main_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">People</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To make the submenus closed, either set the CSS for them to `display:none;` or do `$("li ul").hide();` inside of the `.ready()` function before you define the hover bit.
- This is an unfortunate side-effect of this style of hover menus. There's a jQuery plugin called HoverIntent that I've used before to help this, but in the end I ended up not doing any animation as it's just too tricky to pull off in a nice way.
- It sounds like the `li` elements span a much larger portion of the page than is visible. You may want to check out your CSS for them and limit the height or width of them. So long as `overflow:hidden` isn't set, the submenus should still appear.